# Installation of BusyBox on panda board on Android ICS kernel

Tags: 4.0-ice-cream-sandwich, installation, busybox

I am trying to install BusyBox on panda board which has an ICS Android kernel.

I used the steps below:

1. Download binary file which supports the panda board
2. Push it into `/system/busybox` folder
3. Install the BusyBox command line tools on the target by executing the following commands on booted filesystem:

   ```
   pc ./adb shell
   target$ cd /system/busybox
   target$ ./busybox --install .
   target$ ./sh  #here i am getting error like ./sh: precmd: not found
   ```
4. Save the original sh executable by renaming it, and then create a soft-link to BusyBox sh:

   ```
   target$ cd /system/bin
   target$ mv sh sh.android
   target$ ln -s /system/busybox/sh sh
   ```
5. Export

   ```
   export PATH=$PATH:/system/busybox:/sbin:/vendor/bin:/system/sbin:/system/bin:/system/xbin
   ```

`Step 3` is to install BusyBox, and `step 4` is to make BusyBox shell as default shell. But I am getting an error in the 3rd step. I want to make BusyBox shell as default shell, so I can run scripts on panda board.

I appreciate any type of suggestions or solutions. Thanks in advance.