# Where is the precmd command in android?

Tags: 4.1-jelly-bean, samsung-galaxy-note-2, busybox

I'm kind of used to linux. I'm using Busybox from the Busybox Free installer, with Busybox 1.21.0-Stericson. Trying to chance my shell to the Busybox shell using `busybox ash` gives the following error after every single command:

```
ash: precmd: not found
echo $PS1
$(precmd)$USER@$HOSTNAME:${PWD: -?} $
```

I tried to go back to the normal shell and find out WHERE precmd is:

```
which precmd
```

It just changes the prompt to have "`1|`" in front of it, without giving me WHERE it is. I found a solution [here](http://blog.bstpierre.org/zsh-prompt), but have no idea where to put it. I'm basically trying to do the same as [this question](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/36863/installation-of-busybox-on-panda-board-on-android-ics-kernel) (make Busybox shell the default).

Comment: `precmd` is a function, and as far as I understand ash doesn't support it.

Comment: There was a solution here: http://blog.bstpierre.org/zsh-prompt as I said. I need to find out where to put the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using *Connectbot*: according to an [article at XDA-Developers](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1642623), this is nothing but a cosmetical error:

> Connectbot seems to set shell variable 'PS1' to "$(precmd)$USER@$HOSTNAME:${PWD:-?} $ ".
>   It means your shell (the busybox's ash applet) will try to use output from 'precmd' as a part of a command prompt.
>   So when 'precmd' was not provided, error messages will be generated wenever a prompt was to be shown.

To fix this, mentioned post says you can use `PS1="> "` (or simply `unset PS1`) to work around that error.

Comment: Looking for further references, I found you already [cross-posted this to stackoverflow](http://stackoverflow.com/q/14154028) and got an answer there. It would have been fair to update your question here accordingly, as you obviously got a solution there (the same, it seems) which solved your issue.